# Accesing inherited C++ library functions from C

Tags: c++, c

I need to link my c-program with functions from inherited c++ library. The standard way is to use c++ wrappers to define a dummy c-structure that represents the c++ class. That works for simple (not inherited) classes. How can I modify it to work with inherited classes (i.e. air->cloud->lightning)?

Simple case:

```
typedef struct lightning lightning;
```

Comment: C will be completely incapable of understanding inheritance, so you need to export each sub-class as its own seprate type. You could just give up and YOLO it with `void*` for all these, deal with the mapping back via `static_cast` in the C++ domain, but that's a last resort.

Comment: Thx for your fast reply. A simple example to demonstrate your point?

Comment: It really depends on what sort of objects, classes and such you're exporting and if templates are involved or not. Using C in C++ is usually easy. The reverse not so much.

Comment: I am a strong C programmer, noob with C++. No templates in the functions I am interested. I have exported the last subclass that has the function of interest, but I will have to look into it more. Thx for pointing me to the right direction

Comment: In a lot of cases you'll want a script to auto-generate this for you, or at the least some macros to make it less error-prone. If your C++ functions take things like references, or Standard Library objects like `std::string` or `std::vector` you'll have to figure out how you want to represent that in C.

Comment: The low-tech way is to just bang out things like `void* lighting_new(char* name)` which maps to `return (void*) new Lightning(name)` or something.

Comment: When a C program needs to to use *any* feature of C++ that has no equivalent in C, it is necessary to explicitly handle the mapping from C++ to C.  For inheritance (C++, not part of C), that means you need to explicitly export something that represents EACH derived class needed by the C code.  For templates, EACH instantiation of a C++ template that will be used from C needs some representation explicitly exported to C.  The need for less explicit mapping (whether sending data from C to C++, from C++ to C, or both) is a reason that calling C from C++ is more common than calling C++ from C

Comment: Thx Peter. I think it will be much easier to just build a c++ simple program to link against the c++ library. All that sounds too much work, to someone like me that is only a noob c++ programmer. I can always write c++ programs with c;-)